# How to start/restart of script after another service is ready?

Tags: mysql, php, supervisor

We use Supervisor to manage some PHP scripts that need to interact with a local MySQL server. This works well under normal operation when those PHP scripts themselves exit after error. But when system boots or after MySQL server crashes, because MySQL server needs a few minutes to boot, those PHP scripts will behave erratically when MySQL server is still booting.

My question is, is there a way to check whether MySQL service ready in Supervisor first then start/restart PHP scripts? If this cannot be done in Supervisor, can we do it with some other application?

There seems to be a way to manage this during system boot via systemd, basically don't start Supervisor itself until MySQL service is ready. But this doesn't handle MySQL crash/reboot after system boot.

Can anyone offer some pointers?

Thanks in advance,
ZL